# In Excel, how do i create a formula to tell me if the last entry is new from the last 6 results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to get a formula that's a bit above my level, and hope someone can help.

I have in column "K" numbers, randomly from 1 to 12 depending on other results.ie, column K, row 2 =5, row 3 =8, row 4 =8, row 5 =11 etc.

I would like to have a formula in Column "L" telling me if the entered number is a different result from the last 6 numbers (results). The Key here being NOT necessarily the last 6 numbers total, as there may be a repeat number or two, which would mean the formula would have to look for more than the last 6 cells sometimes to give an accurate answer, "R" for repeat, "N" for No Repeat.
This is where I'm stuck, I am using the formula:

```
=IF(K8="0","0",IF(K8=K2,"R",IF(K8=K3,"R",IF(K8=K4,"R",IF(K8=K5,"R",IF(K8=K6,"R",IF(K8=K7,"R","N")))))))
```

But that only counts the last immediate 6 cells and doesnt allow for repeat numbers in the last 6.

I have added a screenshot of an example below to help clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

You can see in cell L13 the current formula gives me a "N" result as there is no "7" in the last 6 cells, However it is a REPEAT because there are two 2's & 4's in the above cells, so K13 "7" is a repeat of the last 6 numbers.

[image: Example Picture]

Comment: Please try to clarify your question, both concerning wording and structure. Perhaps also provide sample range of data from column "K" and corresponding expected result in column "L" covering the various possible "repeat" combinations. If, on the other hand, you have solved the issue somehow else, and you don't expect an answer anymore, please delete the question.

Comment: @Tom Brungerg, you are 100% correct in your comments below, and thanks for your suggestions. I have added an example picture that i hope makes it clearer to all what im trying to achieve. Im still hoping for an answer, but it seems its not an easy fix!

Answer (score -3):

I would like to suggest a two-step solution to find the last 6 entries in the column and then report whether the Entered Number is different from those numbers.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Fill this array formula down from B2 to find the last 6 entries in Column A:

```
{=OFFSET(A1,COUNT(A$1:A$21),0,-6)}
```

Write this array Formula in Cell E3, to check the Entered Number in Cell E2.

```
{=IF(E2=B2:B7,E2&" Found in Range",E2&" Not  found in Range")}
```

Note:

- Enter both formulas with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.
- And feel free to change the data range as necessary.

.

Comment: Once again, this answer does not solve the OP's problem. He points out that there is the possibility of duplicates in column K, and he wants to check whether the last number in column K (***not*** the number you've arbitrarily entered in E2) is one of the previous 6 **unique values** in column K. Your answer completely ignores the need to check against the last 6 **unique** values.

Comment: @Bandersnatch, This has written by the OP, " have a formula in Column "L" telling me if the entered number is a different result from the last 6 numbers (results). ", no where OP mentioned specifically that the last number is entered in Col K, so that I picked a different Cell E2 and if the entered number is even in Col K only one cell has to be matched with last 6 entries,,,, so that the METHOD i've used is correct, the main issue was to find last 6 entries without  VBA and I've done it.

Comment: How are you addressing this requirement: *The Key here being NOT necessarily the last 6 numbers total, as there may be a repeat number or two, which would mean the formula would have to look for more than the last 6 cells sometimes...*?

Comment: @Rajesh S, thanks for your input, but it wasn't what i was after. I have added a picture to help explain, hope it makes it easier to understand.